# The performance of mysql fulltext depend on order of keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am having problem with mysql fulltext search. When I change the order of keyword, the search speed changes. For example I have 4 queries, all of them return same result:

1) FAST (1s)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+english*
>   +php*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

2) SLOW (10s)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php*
>   +english*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

3) FAST (1s)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php*' IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE) AND (MATCH (column_data)) AGAINST('+english*' IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE))

4) SLOW (10s)

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+english*' IN
>   BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (MATCH (column_data) AGAINST('+php*' IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE))

How can I optimize it?

Comment: so its means there is data difference of each keyword

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam 4 queries have same result

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer. That is because number of results of each keyword. We should put the keyword has small result on the top.